# Class constructor and interfaces

Tags: class, typescript, interface

How do I properly type Classes that implement interfaces?

Example code:

```
interface IPlugin{
  name:string;
}

class SomePlugin implements IPlugin{
  name;
  constructor(){
    this.name = 'Sam';
  }
}

const arrayOfClass:IPlugin = [SomePlugin];
// Ther error :
/*
Type 'typeof SomePlugin[]' is not assignable to type 'IPlugin'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type 'typeof SomePlugin[]'.
*/
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: A Banana is a fruit, but a box of bananas isn't a fruit. Same thing here: a SomePlugin is an IPlugin, but an array of SomePlugin is not an IPlugin. So this code doesn't make much sense, but it's hard to advise what to do without knowing what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, it's even worse than that. You don't have a bow of bananas, but a box containing the recipe used to grow a banana, i.e. an array containing the type SomePlugin.

Comment: Trying to create an array of class constructors that implement IPlugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface that describes objects that will instantiate objects that implement `IPlugin`. You can do this by using a new signature:

```
interface IPluginConstructor {
    new(...args: any[]): IPlugin;
}
```

Now type `arrayOfClass` as an array of `IPluginConstructor`s:

```
const arrayOfClass: IPluginConstructor[] = [SomePlugin];
```

Note the `[]` in the type. That was absent in the question.

**Sidenote**

If you look closely, the type of `name` is `any` in `SomePlugin`... it's been set as `any` because the type was implicitly typed as `any` and `string` is assignable to `any`. That means the following code compiles:

```
const s = new SomePlugin();
const num: number = s.name; // this compiles... sad! :(
```

You should type that either explicitly...

```
class SomePlugin implements IPlugin {
  name: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Sam';
  }
}
```

...or implicitly...

```
class SomePlugin implements IPlugin {
  name = 'Sam';
}
```

I recommend you enable the `noImplicitAny` compiler flag to help catch these kind of mistakes in the future.